# How to get data from servlet by extjs

Tags: asp.net, extjs

i create an jsonarray and sent from servlet, and sent to the front side, 
the front side should get the message and currentTime, and show them in the website. How should i do that in EXTjs:
Here is the code in the servelet:

```
public void loadHistory(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray dataArray = new JsonArray();
        String groupName = request.getParameter("groupName");
        String chatRoomName = getChatRoom(groupName);

        Database db = new Database(chatRoomName);
        CouchDbClient dbClient = db.getDbClient();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


        int i=0;
        while (dbClient.contains(String.valueOf(i++))){
            JsonObject objHistory = dbClient.find(JsonObject.class, String.valueOf(i++));
            String preMessage = objHistory.get("message").getAsString();
            String preTime = objHistory.get("currentTime").getAsString();
            json.addProperty("message", preMessage);
            json.addProperty("currentTime", preTime);
            dataArray.add(json);
        }
        if (dataArray!=null){
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            out.print(dataArray);
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you include a example json string. This would help all those that know extjs, but that don't know asp. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

modify  the below code in the if conditon before sending the response.

```
  if (dataArray!=null){
         response.setContentType("application/json");
         JSONObject resultJsonMain=new JSONObject();
         resultJsonMain.put("resultJsonMain",dataArray);
         out.println(resultJsonMain);

        out.close();
    }
```